# alpha and fill legends in ggplot2 boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, legend, alpha

I'm trying to combine `alpha` and `fill` aesthetics.  It works when I'm using `geom_bar` (or `geom_points`, for `color`), but the alpha legend doesn't work in when I'm using `geom_boxplot`.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
dt = data.table(x = rep(1:5,6), y = rnorm(30),
               tag1 = rep(c('hey', 'what'), 15),
               tag2 = rep(c('yeah', 'yeah', 'so', 'so', 'so'), 6))
```

It works for bars:

```
ggplot(dt[, list(y = mean(y)), by = list(x, tag1, tag2)],
       aes(x = x, y = y, fill = tag1, alpha = tag2,
           group = interaction(x,tag1,tag2))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

But not for boxplot - the alpha legend is empty.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = tag1, alpha = tag2,
               group = interaction(x, tag1, tag2))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

A simpler version can be done with no fill - it seems like bar defaults to gray/lightgray, and boxplot defaults to white/lightwhite:

```
ggplot(dt[, list(y = mean(y)), by = list(x, tag2)],
       aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = tag2,
           group = interaction(x,tag2))) +
 geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = tag2,
               group = interaction(x, tag2))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

But I'm not really sure how to fix this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why ggplot doesn't actually provide the alpha levels in the legend for boxplots, but you can hard code it using `override.aes`. (Editorial note: I find the alpha aesthetic a bit confusing for either the boxplot or the bar plot. It's hard to mentally separate the transparency from the fill color and the grey-scale alpha legend exacerbates the problem, because nothing is mapped to grey in the plot.)

In the code below, to improve visibility of the legend, I've removed the box lines from the `alpha` legend and increased the legend key height. I've also edited the aesthetics to remove the need for the `group` argument.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, fill=tag1, alpha=tag2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.2,0.7)) +
  guides(alpha=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=hcl(c(15,195),100,0,alpha=c(0.2,0.7)),
                                              colour=NA))) +
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(1,"cm"))
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `interaction` for both the fill and alpha aesthetics, but it turns out ggplot doesn't include any colors in that case:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, alpha=interaction(tag1,tag2)), 
       fill=interaction(tag1,tag2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(hcl(c(15,195),100,65), 2)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=rep(c(0.3, 1), each=2)) +
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(2,"cm"))
```

[image]

So, instead you can do it all with the fill aesthetic, but include transparency in the colour specification. This works, but, once again, because transparency and color are somewhat intermingled in visual perception, it's probably better to just go with four different colors.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, fill=interaction(tag1,tag2,sep="-"))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195,15,195),100,65, alpha=c(0.4,0.4,1,1))) +
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(1,"cm")) +
  labs(fill="Tag 1 - Tag 2")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It's strange that there's different behavior between bar and boxplot, and that it has to be fixed so manually, but this definitely works!  I agree that in this example the alpha is confusing.  In my final result, I'm using alpha to distinguish between the theoretical result (transparent) and the more messy result you get due to sampling error, etc.  So I *think* it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a lot of time has passed since the question was posted, but as of the day of the publication of this response, the solution is to add this line of code (passing color and alpha values to the **alpha function**):

```
scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), .3))
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I don't think that actually works, though - the alpha legend still just has two white boxplots.

e.g. with

`ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = tag1, alpha = tag2,
               group = interaction(x, tag1, tag2))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), .3))`

Comment: .. can't figure out how to format that properly.