# Add continous / discrete alpha scale with custom color

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I made a graph using ggplot2 and I used `alpha` to achieve a gradient. I would like to somehow visualize the use of `alpha` in the legend. As can be seen in the plot, I just get empty boxplot-legend-items. I am not even sure why it shows alpha in a discrete way, since I give it an integer variable for scaling it. I would like the legend to display alpha in a continous or discrete way and the color gray (like, from medium to dark gray) or in another way making sense. How can I do this? I always struggle with alpha legends somehow.

Here is the current plot:

[image]

Here is some dummy data and the code:

```
fluct_all <- data.frame(
  "type" = rep(c("tls", "tls_rgb", "tls_geo", "tls_rgb_geo"), each=50),
  "fold" = rep(1:5, 10),
  "test_acc" = rnorm(200))

ggplot(fluct_all, aes(x = type, y = test_acc, alpha = fold, fill = type, group = interaction(type, fold))) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", alpha = 1, width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0, outlier.size = 0, fill = "white", alpha = 1, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.01, outlier.size = 0.75, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    # values = color_scale_class,
    name = "Input Data\nCombination",
    labels = c("TLS", "TLS & GEO", "TLS & RGB", "ALL")
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  # theme(
  #   text = element_text(size = 14, family = "Calibri"),
  #   legend.title = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 16),
  #   legend.key.width = unit(0.75, "cm"),
  #   legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
  #   legend.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 14)
  # ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("TLS", "TLS & GEO", "TLS & RGB", "ALL")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Test Accuracy\n") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.5, 1), name = "\nFold")
```

Comment: Related: [alpha and fill legends in ggplot2 boxplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612971/alpha-and-fill-legends-in-ggplot2-boxplots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `override.aes` in `guide_legend()` to change the look of the `alpha` legend. For example, add an overall fill color and then an alpha value for each of the 5 boxes. I used `seq()` to make an even sequence  of alpha values but I'm not sure if that is the best option.

I did this all in `scale_alpha_continuous()` via the `guide` argument:

```
guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "grey24",
                                         alpha = seq(.5, 1, length.out = 5)))
```

Here's the whole plot and output.

```
ggplot(fluct_all, aes(x = type, y = test_acc, alpha = fold, fill = type, group = interaction(type, fold))) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", alpha = 1, width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0, outlier.size = 0, fill = "white", alpha = 1, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.01, outlier.size = 0.75, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(
        # values = color_scale_class,
        name = "Input Data\nCombination",
        labels = c("TLS", "TLS & GEO", "TLS & RGB", "ALL")
    ) +
    theme_light() +
    # theme(
    #     text = element_text(size = 14, family = "Calibri"),
    #     legend.title = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 16),
    #     legend.key.width = unit(0.75, "cm"),
    #     legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
    #     legend.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 14)
    # ) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("TLS", "TLS & GEO", "TLS & RGB", "ALL")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Test Accuracy\n") +
    scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.5, 1), name = "\nFold",
                           guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "grey24",
                                                                    alpha = seq(.5, 1, length.out = 5))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I can't think of another nice way to symbolize alpha in the legend, so this is fine.